# TapGestures not working inside custom TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uikit, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm adding a TapGestureRecognizer to an UIImageView at my custom TableViewCell but it's not calling its action. **When I tap on the Image, it triggers the didSelectRowAt delegate method of tableview. I am not using any storyboard or .xib**. I have done this a thousand times with UI created via .xib with no problems, but I don't understand why programmatically this does not work. Any idea?

At my custom TableViewCell:

```
var favButton = UIImageView()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    addSubview(favButton)
    configureFavButton()      
}

func set(stock: Stock) {
        self.stock = stock
        favButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill")?.withTintColor(.black, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
    }

func configureFavButton() {

    // Creating constraints using SnapKit 
    favButton.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.width.equalTo(30)
    }
    
    favButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    favButton.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeFromFavorites)))

}

@objc func removeFromFavorites() {
    guard let stock = stock else { return }
    delegate?.removeFromFavorites(stock)
}
```

At my ViewController, when defining my cell at cellForRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FavoriteCell") as! FavoriteCell
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.set(stock: model.favorites[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Comment: That's probably because the target is wrong.

Comment: @ElTomato could you explain in detail? I mean, target should be 'self', as the method is at the UITableViewCell class, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the subView (favButton) to the cell's contentView rather than the view itself

```
contentView.addSubview(favButton)
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem. You saved my day! <3

Comment: give me a hug, bro <3